# How to check if item exist in DB on Windows Azure mobile service project

Tags: c#, azure

I'm trying to look for Person with username and password and if exist on DB to enter the application.

I don't know what to use to find my items on DB and this is my try:

private async void bt_login_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

```
        var temperson = new Person();
        temperson.UserName = tb_username.Text;
        temperson.Password = tb_password.Text;
        foreach (var person in personTable)
        {
            if((person.UserName == tb_username.Text) && (person.Password == tb_password.Text))
                NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Pages/FacebookLoginPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));

        }

    }
```

This is how persontabel define

> private IMobileServiceTable personTable = App.MobileService.GetTable();

Answer (score 1):

I think this question is much more generic and unrelated to mobile services. As it stands, you've written client-side code to march through server-side data, hunting for a given Person. What happens when you have 10,000 Persons? A million? This is much better dealt with server-side (either via app-tier code or in a stored procedure), but... that's just my opinion.

If you're really trying to use Mobile Services for this task, then build some type of login/authentication API call into your mobile service stack. Pass the username and [hashed/encrypted] password to the mobile stack, have it search for the user via db query, perform password-match, and return something that tells you whether the Person was found+authenticated. *How* you do that is really up to you - lots of ways, and there's no single right answer.